# how to fetch image from static assets for elm with phoenix backend?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

An image from the elm front requires an image stored in static/images:

```
background : Model -> Html Msg
background model =
    img
        [ src "assets/static/images/main_bg.jpg)"
        ]
        []
```

I've tried using `priv/static/images/main_bg.jpg` but get the same error:

```
 ** (Phoenix.Router.NoRouteError) no route found for GET /assets/static/images/main_bg.jpg (PlatformWeb.Router)
    (platform) lib/phoenix/router.ex:324: PlatformWeb.Router.call/2
    (platform) lib/platform_web/endpoint.ex:1: PlatformWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
    (platform) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: PlatformWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
    (platform) lib/platform_web/endpoint.ex:1: PlatformWeb.Endpoint.call/2
    (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:42: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/4
```

Comment: Can you give us the route definition that should serve /assets and does the file exist?

Comment: The default location would be at `/images/main_bg.jpg`. I could be different based on your configuration though.

Comment: `/images/main_bg.jpg` gives me the same result. As for the route definition I'm not sure where that is. To setup the elm relationship, i set a div id in the template as used that as a node in `/assets/js/app.js` with ```// Elm
import { Elm } from "../elm/src/Main.elm"

Elm.Main.init({
    node: document.getElementById("elm-container")
})```

Answer (score 1):

You are making a `GET` request to the endpoint `/assets/static/images/main_bg.jpg`, but no route is defined for it.

If you want to serve the content of the `images` folder (i.e. `priv/static/images/main_bg.jpg`), you could use the [Plug.Static](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Static.html) in your Phoenix Endpoint (`lib/my_app_web/endpoint.ex`).

Make sure to add `images` to the `:only` option, if you want to specify what exactly it is going to be served:

```
defmodule MyApp.Endpoint do
  use Phoenix.Endpoint, otp_app: :my_app

  # Serve at "/" the static files from "priv/static" directory.
  #
  # You should set gzip to true if you are running phx.digest
  # when deploying your static files in production.
  plug Plug.Static,
    at: "/",
    from: :my_app,
    gzip: true,
    only: ~w(images asset-manifest.json manifest.json)
```

At last, dont forget to change your image src to `"images/main_bg.jpg"`.